# Per-project texmf directory

Tags: fonts, texmf

Is it possible to specify a texmf directory from within a tex file? I think a project-specific way to set the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable, instead of within the `~/.bashrc` file would work.

**Motivation**
I mostly use the Kile LaTeX editor on KDE, but I synchronise my TeX project tree over to other computers using `git`; on OSX I have MacTex installed.

I've just installed the Myriad Pro OTF font package using [Michael Gährken's package](http://www.gaehrken.de/fonts/), and would like this font to be used on all machines without having to edit local files and folders on each host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change the `kpathsea` (pseudo)environment variables once the `pdftex` process has been started. But you can change their value *before* launching the process:

```bsh
TEXMFHOME="/path/to/new/texmfhome:$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)" pdflatex filename
```

This will prepend the "new home" to the current value; the syntax used assumes `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (+1)! I figure the LaTeX builder (e.g. Kile/MacTex) should allow configuration of the build environment. Kile, at least though, doesn't seem to have settings to configure the build commands' environment; only the commands' arguments. So to make this work (on KDE), I'd have to set `TEXMFHOME` in `/etc/environment` (or whichever file it is that configures the global KDE environment). Would you consider this a bug/limitation of Kile? Can I define `TEXMFHOME` in a project-specific config file or something?

Comment: @AlexLeach Sorry, I don't know whether Kile is able to cope with this; but I'm pretty sure you can send an arbitrary shell command for typesetting also with it.

Comment: Good point. The template I'm using came with a Makefile, which I haven't been using, but I can configure Kile (and MacTex I imagine) to just run `make`. Obviously I've got to add your changes to the Makefile, but that will do :)