# Install custom .cls using TeX Live in local directory

Tags: installing, texlive, document-classes, linux

## Background

There is a `.cls` file that `pdflatex` should use. I have read the following

- [How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree)
- [Per-project texmf directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/per-project-texmf-directory)
- [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)
- [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package/8359#8359)

Using TeX Live 2012, installed into `/usr/local/texlive/`.

I would like to install the `.cls` file into `$HOME/.texmf` (or some other non-standard directory), rather than `$HOME/texmf`. I thought this would be:

```
mkdir $HOME/.texmf
initexmf --register-root=$HOME/.texmf
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME $HOME/.texmf
mv amazingbook.cls $HOME/.texmf
latex amazing-stories-1.tex
```

## Problem

The `initexmf` program does not exist (in TeX Live 2012). I have read that the `mktexlsr` command is equivalent to `initexmf`.

## Update

Ran:

```
mktexlsr $HOME/.texmf
mv amazingbook.cls $HOME/.texmf
mktexlsr $HOME/.texmf
```

The `.cls` file cannot be found when running:

```
pdflatex amazing-stories-1.tex
```

## Question

What are the exact steps necessary to install a custom `.cls` file into a given directory and configure the environment so that the `.cls` file is visible from LaTeX using TeX Live 2012?

Comment: AFAIK `initexmf` is MikTeX-specific; MikTeX can easily handle many texmf trees.

Comment: `initexmf` is a multi-purpose tool. `initexmf --update` is the equivalent to `mktexlsr`, but `initexmf --register-root` is a (wonderful) miktex specific feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following commands create the required directory hierarchy and register the `.cls` file:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.texmf/tex/latex/amazing
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME $HOME/.texmf
mv amazingbook.cls $HOME/.texmf/tex/latex/amazing
mktexlsr $HOME/.texmf
latex amazing-stories-1.tex
```

The `pdflatex` command can now find `amazingbook.cls`.

Answer (score 5):

Hello I had the same problem and found a suitable and easy solution.

With

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

find your personal tex home directory, where you would put your own .cls files. On my Ubuntu with texlive 2013 it will show "~/texmf" which can lead to a misunderstandung.

Check it again with:

```
kpsepath -n latex tex
```

which will show all folders where latex will search for .cls files. Here it can be seen that the folder is: **~/texmf/tex/latex**.
Copy your file in this folder. Make a update with:

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

Check if it worked with:

```
kpsewhich my_class_file.cls
```

This should show path where you copied the file!

Here are some references:
https://www.math.hmc.edu/computing/support/tex/installing/
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=17242