# How do I install a custom .cls and .bst file on Fedora 20?

Tags: lyx, texlive

I would like to add a `.cls` and a `.bst` file to texlive that will then be found by LyX.

Is there a preferred way to do this?

I would prefer a solution that will last a while / won't have to be fixed every time I change something about my OS.

Comment: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `.cls` to some folder that your tex distribution can find, for compiling. You can for example make a folder in your home directory and register it with tex. Then you can easily keep your folder of tex goodies when you wipe your machine. See [this Q & A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96976/install-custom-cls-using-tex-live-in-local-directory) for details.

Secondly, you need to make LyX aware of the package you added. See [this Q & A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-to-install-an-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-mac). I don't know what the path in Step 3 is on Fedora, but on Ubuntu, I have my LyX layout files in `~/.lyx/layouts/`.

For the `.bst` file, see [this LyX Wiki entry](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Tips) under **Creating your own style file with custom-bib**.

I hope the guides are specific enough, and I apologize for not typing in all the content here. Please comment if you have problems.