# How to draw Young diagrams in LyX

Tags: lyx, diagrams

I would like to draw Young diagrams with LyX.

I found the LaTeX package [yountab](http://ctan.org/pkg/youngtab) which allows me to draw such diagrams in LaTeX,  but I have no idea how to install it on LyX.

How should I go about drawing Young diagrams using LyX?

Comment: Welcome to the world of LyX, LaTeX, TeX.sx and friends ☺

Comment: For installation of packages with LyX, [this answer][1] provides you with information and links.


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214291/12558

Comment: Or one can use one of the ‘batteries-included’ TeX distributions, like [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) or [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’m not familiar with Young tableaux and diagrams, but I think the package [`ytableau`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) is better and more fully developed than `youngtab`.

In order to use it in LyX you need:

1. Add `\usepackage{ytableau}` in the preamble (Document → Settings… → LaTeX Preamble (last one)).
2. Wherever you want to add a Young tableau use [ERT](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT) (LaTeX inside LyX, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> shortcut) and add whatever code you want (`ytableau` documentation is available [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ytableau/ytableau.pdf)).

Maybe there is a more LyXish way to do that. I don’t use LyX.

Example:

[image: LyX screenshot]

[image: LyX output]

I hope that helps you ☺

Comment: What is meaning of **cr**? Line when writing matrices, we end one row by double-slash; similarly, when closing one row in tableaux, I think cr is used; but I want to know its long-form.

Answer (score 7):

(This builds on Júda's answer, which you should accept, but is a bit too long for a comment.)

You can make the diagrams easier to edit in LyX using this dirty hack. After the `\usepackage` command in the preamble, add this:

```
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}{\begin{ytableau}}{\end{ytableau}}
```

Usually, the `bmatrix` environment will create a matrix with square brackets around it. This command changes it to make a Young tableau instead. (You can still get a matrix with square brackets by inserting the brackets separately from the matrix.) Now you can create your diagram by typing `\bmatrix` and pressing space in a math equation, then using the toolbar buttons to add rows and columns. For example, if you put this into an equation:

[image: editing a ytableu]

then you'll get an output like this (if you have instant preview turned on then it'll appear as soon as you take your cursor out of the equation):

[image: previewing a ytableu]