# Where should Springer SV Mult be placed on a Linux Mint Computer?

Tags: lyx, texlive

I am trying to install the "Springer SV Mult" document class for use in Lyx V2.2.2. The OS is Linux Mint 18 with Texlive. I downloaded ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svmultt1.zip but can't figure out where to create the "springer" folder that contains these files so that Lyx will see it and allow me to use this document class. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you install them so that LaTeX can see them (google for how to install a LaTeX class on Linux), then in LyX do Tools > Reconfigure and LyX will become aware.

Comment: That is my problem. I can't seem to find the location on this computer to place the files that will allow the process will work. I got it to work on a Windows computer with Miktex with the help given at https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Springer, but they don't cover how to do it with a Linux computer.

Comment: I see, so the problem doesn't actually have anything to do with LyX. take a look at the following: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96976/install-custom-cls-using-tex-live-in-local-directory