# Project-local texmf directory

Tags: texlive, texmf, git

I'd like track my LaTeX projects using git, especially when collaborating with other authors. I'd also like to track my texmf directory in a separate git repository. My desire is to add my texmf repository as a git submodule to each LaTeX project. However, I can't figure out how to tell latexmk (really, pdflatex) to see my project-local texmf.

Ultimately, I want my LaTeX projects to be standalone, i.e. they depend on nothing other a TeX Live install and the files in the project directory so they can seamlessly be compiled on different machines or in a CI pipeline. How can this be done?

Note: I have tried the solutions presented in similar questions, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/per-project-texmf-directory) (the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable seems to be ignored) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree?rq=1) (requires updating system texmf.cnf), to no success so far.

Comment: In case you are using texlive, you could add arbitrary auxtrees. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632156/4736 or manual pages of tlmgr, which you also get with `tlgmr help`.